# How to loop over json array from facebook graph API

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, facebook-graph-api

How can I loop over a json array that looks like the one below, using python?
{

```
"insights": {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "page_impressions",
            "period": "day",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 14,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                    "value": 17,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
            ],
            "title": "Daily Total Impressions",
            "description": "Daily: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
            "id": "/insights/page_impressions/day"
        },
        {
            "name": "page_impressions",
            "period": "week",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 14,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                    "value": 31,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
            ],
            "title": "Weekly Total Impressions",
            "description": "Weekly: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
            "id": "/insights/page_impressions/week"
        },
        {
            "name": "page_impressions",
            "period": "days_28",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 14,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                    "value": 31,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
            ],
            "title": "28 Days Total Impressions",
            "description": "28 Days: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
            "id": "/insights/page_impressions/days_28"
        }
    ]
```

I know how to loop over individual items:

```
values = profile['insights']['data'][0]['values'][0]
```

But this isn't a feasible solution considering that I need to loop over every item and display the output and store it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code example you gave shows how to access a specific nested element (i.e. the first value from 'values', in the first 'data' element in 'insights') - what exactly do you mean by "loop over"? What values are you looking to extract and what do you need them for? (that is, how are you going to use them and in what format or data type do they need to be)

Comment: @Grismar basically I need to get the values (value and end-time individually) from all three periods (day, week, 28) and store them through an api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to iterate the json, this is one way you could do it:

Data:

```
test = {
    "insights": {
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "page_impressions",
                "period": "day",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": 14,
                        "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 17,
                        "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Daily Total Impressions",
                "description": "Daily: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
                "id": "/insights/page_impressions/day"
            },
            {
                "name": "page_impressions",
                "period": "week",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": 14,
                        "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 31,
                        "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Weekly Total Impressions",
                "description": "Weekly: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
                "id": "/insights/page_impressions/week"
            },
            {
                "name": "page_impressions",
                "period": "days_28",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": 14,
                        "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 31,
                        "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "28 Days Total Impressions",
                "description": "28 Days: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
                "id": "/insights/page_impressions/days_28"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Code:

```
for data in test["insights"]["data"]:
    print(data["title"])
    for value in data["values"]:
        print(value)
```

Result:

```
Daily Total Impressions
{'value': 14, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000'}
{'value': 17, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000'}
Weekly Total Impressions
{'value': 14, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000'}
{'value': 31, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000'}
28 Days Total Impressions
{'value': 14, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000'}
{'value': 31, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000'}
```

If you need to unpack it even further:

```
for data in test["insights"]["data"]:
    print(data["title"])
    for val in data["values"]:
        for key, value in val.items():
            print(f"The value: [ {value} ]")
```

Result:

```
Daily Total Impressions
The value: [ 14 ]
The value: [ 2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000 ]
The value: [ 17 ]
The value: [ 2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000 ]
Weekly Total Impressions
The value: [ 14 ]
The value: [ 2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000 ]
The value: [ 31 ]
The value: [ 2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000 ]
28 Days Total Impressions
The value: [ 14 ]
The value: [ 2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000 ]
The value: [ 31 ]
The value: [ 2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
profile = {
"insights": {
"data": [
{
    "name": "page_impressions",
    "period": "day",
    "values": [
        {
            "value": 14,
            "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "value": 17,
            "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Daily Total Impressions",
    "description": "Daily: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
    "id": "/insights/page_impressions/day"
},
{
    "name": "page_impressions",
    "period": "week",
    "values": [
        {
            "value": 15,
            "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "value": 31,
            "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Weekly Total Impressions",
    "description": "Weekly: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
    "id": "/insights/page_impressions/week"
},
{
    "name": "page_impressions",
    "period": "days_28",
    "values": [
        {
            "value": 16,
            "end_time": "2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
            "value": 33,
            "end_time": "2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000"
        }
    ],
    "title": "28 Days Total Impressions",
    "description": "28 Days: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
    "id": "/insights/page_impressions/days_28"
}
]}}
```

There are 2 ways to do it:

Option (1) fixed schema

```
result = []
for i in range(3):
    temp = []
    for j in range(2):
        temp.append(profile['insights']['data'][i]['values'][j])
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

Option (2) for any schema

```
def get_vals(nested, key):
    result = []
    if isinstance(nested, list) and nested != []:   #non-empty list
        for lis in nested:
            result.extend(get_vals(lis, key))
    elif isinstance(nested, dict) and nested != {}:   #non-empty dict
        for val in nested.values():
            if isinstance(val, (list, dict)):   #(list or dict) in dict
                result.extend(get_vals(val, key))
        if key in nested.keys():   #key found in dict
            result.append(nested[key])
    return result

result = get_vals(profile, 'values')
print(result)
```

Both options will output:

```
[[{'value': 14, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000'},
  {'value': 17, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000'}],
 [{'value': 15, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000'},
  {'value': 31, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000'}],
 [{'value': 16, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00+0000'},
  {'value': 33, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00+0000'}]]
```

After that you could place them in a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result).T
df.columns = ['Daily Total Impressions', 'Weekly Total Impressions', '28 Days Total Impressions']
```

Output

```
                             Daily Total Impressions  \
0  {'value': 14, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00...   
1  {'value': 17, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00...   

                            Weekly Total Impressions  \
0  {'value': 15, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00...   
1  {'value': 31, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00...   

                           28 Days Total Impressions  
0  {'value': 16, 'end_time': '2022-05-16T07:00:00...  
1  {'value': 33, 'end_time': '2022-05-17T07:00:00...
```